# How to find the lines through the point $(2, 2, 0)$?

Tags: calculus, geometry

In the real space $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a cylinder with an axis $x = 0$, $y = z$ and a radius of $2$.

Find the lines through the point $(2, 2, 0)$, which are parallel to the plane $x + y + z = 2$, and both touch the cylinder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the equation of the line be $$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}2\\2\\0\end{matrix}\right)+\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}p\\q\\r\end{matrix}\right)$$

This line is parallel to the given plane, so $$\left(\begin{matrix}p\\q\\r\end{matrix}\right).\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right)=0$$

The axis of the cylinder is $$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)+\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$

Now use the formula in terms of cross-product for the perpendicular distance between two skew lines  and set this distance equal to 2 to obtain an equation for $p$ and $q$